# Service Fabric disable node type for Services with non-specific placement constraints

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have an Azure SF cluster with several node types:

1. Management (used for the management nodes, no apps are hosted here)
2. Misc (used for all micro services that do not care about their placement)
3. AppX (used for specific application `XXX`, which also specifies `NodeType==AppX` as placement constraint)

How can I make `Misc` node type, as the only node type to host applications being deployed on the cluster, without a specific placement constraint?

This way, I accomplish the comment on #1, and I can make sure that `XXX` is hosted in `AppX` with no "neighbors" (unless other apps are mistakenly configured with the same placement constraint).

Thanks